# Is it possible to query an IPFS network for the uptime (or at least the blocks added over a given time) of individual nodes?

Tags: ipfs

I’d like to query an IPFS network for the uptime of its nodes individually. That is, over a duration *d* I would like to know roughly how much time a node has been participating in the network. Instead of time, I believe it’s also safe to frame this problem in terms of work and query for the number of blocks added within a time period.

Is there a way to do this?

[crosspost](https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/is-it-possible-to-query-an-ipfs-network-for-uptime-or-at-least-the-blocks-added-over-a-given-time/14756)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is **not really**. See the response on [discuss.ipfs.io](https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/is-it-possible-to-query-an-ipfs-network-for-uptime-or-at-least-the-blocks-added-over-a-given-time-of-nodes-individually/14756/4) for more detail.

If you are fine with a trustful system, you can potentially [expose block add data](https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/is-it-possible-to-query-an-ipfs-network-for-uptime-or-at-least-the-blocks-added-over-a-given-time-of-nodes-individually/14756/4?u=lmonninger) through the RPC. But, this isn't supported out of the box.

Otherwise, you'll have to resort to some kind of [polling and crawling](https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/is-it-possible-to-query-an-ipfs-network-for-uptime-or-at-least-the-blocks-added-over-a-given-time-of-nodes-individually/14756/5?u=lmonninger) it seems.